# Why does Firebase Analytics show 4800 users for my app but Authentication show only 1027?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

My app uses Firebase for authentication and I'm having trouble understanding the discrepancy between the number of authenticated users (1027) and the number of installs (4800):

[image]

[image]

This suggests that a lot of people installed the app but very few logged into it. If so, why would anyone go to the trouble of installing but not using it? Or am I reading Analytics wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to ask about human behavior.  There could be any number of reasons why someone installed an app and deleted it without even signing into it.

We also don't know if you allow users to delete their accounts after signing in, which could also explain a difference.

We don't know if your users have multiple devices, which would each count as different (anonymized) users in Analytics, but the same user account in Authentication.

There could even be robotic crawlers trying to use the app, especially if it's a web app.

If you're having problem reconciling what you see in the console, you're probably better off [contacting Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to see if something is wrong.  But something is probably *not* wrong at all.  Consider instead putting some effort into instrumenting your app with more [analytics events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events) to figure out exactly how people are using it, and where they might be falling off before they ever sign in, or if they sign in with multiple devices.

Comment: Good advice, Doug; thanks. I did contact Firebase support but your suggestion to post analytics events in the app is worth following up on.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Firebase Support and here's what they said:

> The active user calculation in our dashboard is based on the user_engagement of your user who access your application while the app is in foreground state. With that, the active user count is not based on the total count of your authenticated user because we track it using the user_engagement event. This is expected that there would be greater number of active users than your authenticated user count if your user didn’t authenticate and they’re using the app within foreground state.

I turns out that the number of 4800 is the number of "engagements" by the app's users, not the number of users. If the user logs in, then goes to another page, that's two engagements. Firebase Analytics is a great way to analyze what people are doing in the app. I love it!